# Electron: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'file-encryptor'

Tags: electron, atom-editor

I Downloaded the crypto `file-encryptor` module and `fs` module

```
var encryptor = require('file-encryptor');
```

Cleared and cleaned cache from my folder also globally `-g` then cloned cache of `file-encryptor` again and added cache using github cloned link still this error is popping when i create package but before creating it is working absolutely fine.

And my node modules is visible after creating package.